# An equation related to lever

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, statics

To balance a lever, as we know, fulfills $f_1l_1=f_2l_2$, what is the condition that fulfills both $f_1l_1=f_2l_2$ and $f_1+l_1=f_2+l_2$?

Comment: What are the units of $f$ and of $l$?

Comment: "f" is force, and "l" is length.  They have different units.  In physics, it's permissible to multiply and divide variables that have different units, but it is NOT permissible to add and subtract variables that have different units.  Adding forces to lengths doesn't make physics sense.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $f_1 l_1 - f_2 l_2 = 0$ is a mathematical statement  that the torque on the left of the lever (say counter clockwise moment of the force $f_1$) equals the  torque (clockwise moment of the force $f_2$) on the right of the lever.

The equation $f_1 + d_1 = f_2 + d_2$ does not have any meaningful physical interpretation. There does not appear to be any physical condition that satisfies both of these equations simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

As Dr jh stated in an earlier answer, the equation f1 + l1 = f2 + l2 does not appear to have any physical meaning, especially since the f's are forces and the l's are distances; that is, adding a force and a distance seems wrong.  Typically the other equation you need for a balanced lever- in addition to the torque balance (f1 l1 = f2 l2) about the fulcrum point- is the force balance: f1 + f2 = Fc where Fc is the force up at the fulcrum support to balance the net force down f1 + f2.